# Зачем использовать callback функцию(именно передавать ее в качестве аргумента),если можно просто вызвать функцию,которая видна например по замыканию?

Tags: javascript

Уважаемые знатоки,у меня два вопроса. Первый - Зачем спользовать callback функцию(именно передавать ее в качестве аргумента),если можно просто вызвать функцию,которая видна например по замыканию?

```
window.onload = function(){
    function first(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('какой-то API запрос или другая асинхронная операция');
    },1000)
      second();
    }
    function second(){
      console.log('Оброботка запроса');
    }
    first();
    }
```

Теперь передадим функцию second в качестве аргумента.

```
window.onload = function(){
    function first(callback){
    setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('какой-то API запрос или другая асинхронная операция');
    },1000)
      callback();
    }
    function second(){
      console.log('Оброботка запроса');
    }
    first(second);
    }
```

Результат идентичен.

Второй вопрос. С того что я понял, то callback фукнцию вызываем не мы,ее вызывает другая функция, в которую мы этот callback передали. И только эта другая функция знает, когда завершился например запрос на сервер и только после этого вызывает функцию callback.

То есть по логике вещей, если мы передаем функцию second в качестве аргумента, то она становится callback функцией для first, и только после того как выполнится запрос на сервер(в нашем случае setTimeout), будет выполнена функция second.

Но на практике вывод совершенно другой, что в первом что во втором случае:

```
"Оброботка запроса"

"какой-то API запрос или другая асинхронная операция"
```

Почему обработка запроса, которая должна выполнится после запроса на сервер,вызывается раньше,хотя это как бы колбэк функция?
Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: callback тут ни при чём..... проблема в том что текущая функция (в данном случае setTimeout) **асинхронная**

Comment: А вообще не ясен вопрос. В заголовке спрашивается одно, а в теле - совсем другое

Comment: Я отвечал на один вопрос и там можно найти ответ на ваш вопрос. В моем ответе пошаговый разбор работы с [асинхронными функциям и переданными аргументами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452229/%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-settimeout/1452239#1452239)