# Автоматическое снятие checkbox через 10 секунд

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как на JS сделать автоматическое снятие checkbox с id="1" через 10 секунд после нажатия по нему?

```
<input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="1" autocomplete="off">
<label for="1">Выбрать на 10 секунд</label>
```

Comment: setTimeout вам в помощь. Подсмотрите, например вот тут [про setTimeout](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452229/1452239#1452239)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом, всё просто. Нужно повесить событие по нажатию и если поставили флажок - запустить таймер, который по истечении времени снимет флажок. Если же нажатием флажок сняли, то и таймер нужно остановить.
Вот решение:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="cb-1" autocomplete="off">
<label for="1">Выбрать на 10 секунд</label>

<script>
    const cb = document.querySelector('#cb-1');
    let timer;
    cb.onchange = function timerUncheck(event) {
        const checked = event.target.checked;
        const delay = 10000; // задержка в миллисекундах
        if (checked === true) {
            timer = setTimeout(() => event.target.checked = false, delay);
            console.log('Timer started');
        }
        else {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            console.log('Timer stoped');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Ух ты, круто. А про нюанс "если флажок сняли" я и не подумал :) Спасибо